# Class Method Not Being Evaluated NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, class, variables, nomethoderror

I don't understand why I am getting a NoMethodError when I am trying to call the class method "addStudent". 
I added self to change from an instance to a class method, and I triple-checked my syntax to make sure I am referring to the correct object.

I've run a simple puts on both the school object and the method and they are both referring to the same instance of the School class. Here's the code.

```
class School
   attr_accessor :name, :location, :instructors, :students
   attr_reader :ranking
   @@SCHOOLS = []


    def initialize(name, location, ranking, students, instructors)
       @name = name
       @location = location
       @ranking = ranking
       @students = students
       @instructors = instructors
       @@SCHOOLS << self
    end

    def self.setRanking= (ranking)
       @ranking = ranking
    end

    def self.addStudent= (name, grade, semester)
       @students << {:name => name, :grade => grade, :semester => semester}
    end


    def self.removeStudent(name)
         @students.delete_if { |student_hash| student_hash[:name] == name }
    end
end

 school = School.new ("Happy Funtime School", 
"NYC", 
1, 
[   {:name => "Marissa", :grade => "B"},
    {:name=>"Billy", :grade => "F"},
    {:name => "Frank", :grade => "A"},
    {:name => "Sophie", :grade => "C"}  ],
[ 
    {:name=>"Blake", :subject=>"being awesome" },
    {:name=>"Ashley", :subject=>"being better than blake"},
    {:name=>"Jeff", :subject=>"karaoke"}
                                        ]    

)

school.addStudent("Jesus", "Z", "Y")
```

ERROR:

```
 rb:114:in `<main>': undefined method `addStudent' for #<School:0x007fca64099ff8> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Just to add more clarity (or perhaps more confusion)  you created `school` via `school = School.new...`   `school` (lower case) is an instance object, not a class, so it needs instance methods, not class methods.

Answer (score 2):

1. You made the methods `setRanking`, `addStudent`, `removeStudent` as class methods, by prepend them with `self.`.  But you're using the method `addStudent` as instance method. Remove `self.` to make them as instance methods.
2. You're calling `addStduent`, but defined it as `addStudent=` (trailing `=`).

---

```
def setRanking(ranking)
  @ranking = ranking
end

def addStudent(name, grade, semester)
  @students << {:name => name, :grade => grade, :semester => semester}
end


def removeStudent(name)
  @students.delete_if { |student_hash| student_hash[:name] == name }
end
```

Comment: I don't see a misspelling when I do CTRL+F typing in "Student", and I don't know why I would want to remove self. Then I wouldn't be able to use the method, right?

Comment: @user3667382, I mean: replace `def self.addStudent=` with `def addStudent`, `def self.setRanking=` with `def setRanking`.

Comment: Okay. I don't understand why this fixes the problem. I thought I would be covered by Ruby's "syntactic sugar." :/ Thanks though.

Comment: @user3667382, 1. class method -> instance method / 2. typo fix.

Comment: user3667382, do you understand what falsetru is saying?  Here's a simple example: `class A; def self.cm; puts "hi"; end; def im; puts "ho"; end; end`.  `cm` us a class method (because of `self.`); `im` is an instance method.  Let `a` be an instance of `A`: `a=A.new`.  Then `A.cm => "hi"`, `a.im => ho`, but `A.im => NoMethodError: undefined method 'im' for A:Class` and `a.cm => undefined local variable or method 'a' for main:Object`.